# Natural sorting in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have a bunch of nodes with properties that are converted from BigDecimals to string during insert and vice versa during load.

This leads to typical problems during sorting. Values 1, 2, 3, 10 get sorted as 1, 10, 2, 3.

Does cypher has any means of doring natural sorting on strings? Or do we have to convert these properties to doubles or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess the best way is to store them as integers in your db. Also, in the current milestone release, there's a `toInt()` function which you could use to sort.

```
START n=node(*)
WITH toInt(n.stringValue) as nbr
RETURN n
ORDER BY nbr
```

Comment: What about storing them as doubles?

Comment: That's possible as well as Neo4j supports double property types.You can also convert string values to floats with `toFloat(n.value)`.

Comment: But we're still on 1.9 so I guess we'll have to convert the properties for now.

Comment: Yes, just store them as doubles and you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a primary sort on string length?

```
CREATE ({val:"3"}),({val:"6"}),({val:"9"}),({val:"12"}),({val:"15"}),({val:"18"}),({val:"21"})
MATCH (n) RETURN n.val ORDER BY n.val
// 12, 15, 18, 21, 3, 6, 9
MATCH (n) RETURN length(n.val), n.val
// 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 21
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/kb0obm

If you keep converting them back and forth it sounds like it would be better to store them as their proper types in the database.

Comment: I like your idea but this doesn't really work with value like 1.01, 1.1, 2, 2.1.  As for your other remark, afaik there is no support for BigDecimals, so we need to do conversion.